# Constraining allowsCameraControl SCNView property to just pinch/zoom gesture

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, gesture, scncamera

I have a scene where, after some event, I want the user to be able to interact with the camera but just for the `pinch/zoom gesture`. I would like to enable the `allowsCameraControl` SCNView property for this purpose.

When you enable `allowsCameraControl` all gestures are enabled, some of which aren't very intuitive to use nor easy to control. I also need to have the swipe gesture available for something different than controlling the camera.

Is there a way to constrain the camera control to just the `pinch/zoom gesture`? In the documentation I have found a `SCNCameraController` class, but its description is extremely sparse, and haven't figured out how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allowsCameraControl is kinda cool for generic stuff but agreed, sparse docs.  Probably best to implement your own camera control.  It's not too bad - add a cameraEye and cameraFocus nodes, then set with an SCNLookAtConstraint.  Something like this:

```
func setView()
{
 cameraEye.constraints = []
 cameraEye.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 12)
 cameraFocus.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
 let vConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: cameraFocus)
 vConstraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
 cameraEye.constraints = [vConstraint]
}
```

From there - zooming in/out is a matter of just changing the cameraFocus.position, depending on how complex you want it.  Hope that helps!